# Extra lazy fetching results in DBNull

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping

Let's assume following collection:

```
<list name="Items" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="extra">
    <key column="ItemId"/>
    <index column="Sortorder" />
    <one-to-many class="MyProject.Model.Item, MyProject"/>
</list>
```

Originally it was `lazy="true"`, but I wanted to improve performance. This works great as long as there are items. If there aren't any, the following statement results in `System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.`:

```
if (items.Count > 0) { // Type of items: IList<item>
```

This did work with `lazy="true"` though. What am I missing here?

sl3dg3

Edit: Whole stacktrace:

`[InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.]
   System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) +56
   System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value) +28
   NHibernate.Persister.Collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.GetSize(Object key, ISessionImplementor session) +334
   NHibernate.Collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.ReadSize() +132
   NHibernate.Collection.PersistentList.get_Count() +12
   MyProject.Provider.MyProvider.SomeMethod() in [...]`

Second edit:
If I open the collection with the debugger, there is a HResult from source `mscorelib` which sounds as if the error appears already deep down in the .com - world...

Answer (score 0):

From what I see "items" may be null and you are trying to do a Count() on a null value. Best to check if it is null before trying the Count()

Comment: Yes that's what I thought as well - but why doesn't NHibernate initialize an empty list the same way as with `lazy="true"`?

Comment: Not sure, guess its being "extra lazy" ;-) never actually used it myself. I have all my collections/reference lazy, but always fetch them as needed in queries and never rely on lazyloading.